# How to deal with 3 form on the same page?

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, twig

I have a page with 3 forms and they all are independent (the user can complete 0, 1, 2 or 3) :

- the first asks a phone number if the user wants to be called;
- the second do the same if the user wants to be contacted by SMS;
- the third is used if user want to add commentary

**What is the best way to handle this situation?**

Should I repeat my code three times ***in my Controller***?

```
public function myPageAction(Request $request)
{
  // First one
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add...
    ->getForm();

  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
    // some code
  }

  // Second one
  $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add...
    ->getForm();

  $form2->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid() ) {
    // some code
  }

  // Third one
  $form3 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add...
    ->getForm();

  $form3->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form3->isSubmitted() && $form3->isValid() ) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

And ***in Twig*** :

I have a modal for the first one = the user clicks and a modal with the form pops up:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Same for this one, other modal :

```
{{ form_start(form2) }}
{{ form_widget(form2) }}
{{ form_end(form2) }}
```

The third one is at the bottom of the page :

```
{{ form_start(form3) }}
{{ form_widget(form3) }}
{{ form_end(form3) }}
```

I think it's a lot of code and I repeat myself too much, what can I "optimize"? 
The fact that my first and second form are the same, can I "regroup" them in one? I can create a "PhoneType" form but I have no other choice than call it twice in my Controller?

Sorry if there is a lot of question here, but I can summarize it like this maybe : **What is the best practice to handle multiple form on the same page?** (in my controller and my view)

Answer (score 1):

I see the following ways of achieving your target:

1. use compound forms (embed form within a global form),
2. try using something like a multi-step form, see: https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle
3. dynamically modify forms using events: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

But why cannot you embed all those fields in one form? Splitting up the only three fields is like a shooting to a bee using the cannon. I recommend you using third method because is the easiest one.

Comment: I will edit my question, but the form are not visible at the same time : I have a modal for the first one, same for the second and the third is at the bottom. The user can complete, 0, 1, 2 or 3 form on the same page and they don't depend of each other

Comment: They are not required to be valid all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create 1 form with 3 fields. You can show it by row.

```
{{ form_row(nameOfRow)}}
```

Comment: No I can't, I will edit my question maybe it's not clear, but my 3 forms are not visible "in the same time". I have 2 modals (for the first and second form) and the third is at the bottom of the page. So I need to control each !

Answer (score 0):

If the forms are independent from each other you can do 3 twig funtions (twig extension) for render the forms in a template and 3 different actions controller for handle each form submited.

> Twig extension

```
class FormExtension extends \Twig_Extension{

    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_form_1', array($this, 'getFormOne')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_form_2', array($this, 'getFormtwo'))
        ];
    }

     public function getFormOne()
     {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(FormOneType::class,null,[]);

        return $form->createView();
     }

     public function getFormTwo()
     {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(FormTwoType::class,null,[]);

        return $form->createView();
     }

}
```

> template.html.twig

```
{% if formOne is not defined %}
    {% set formOne = get_form_1() %}
{% endif %}
{{ form_start(formOne, {'action': path('route_handle_form_1')) }}
{{ form_row(formOne.field1) }}
{{ form_row(formOne.field2) }}
{{ form_row(formOne._token) }}
{{ form_end(formOne) }}

{% if formTwo is not defined %}
    {% set formTwo = get_form_2() %}
{% endif %}
{{ form_start(formTwo , {'action': path('route_handle_form_2')) }}
{{ form_row(formTwo.field1) }}
{{ form_row(formTwo.field2) }}
{{ form_row(formTwo._token) }}
{{ form_end(formTwo) }}
```

> Controller

```
class FormController extends Controller{


 /**
 * @Route("/form-1", name="route_handle_form_1")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function handleFormOneAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->formFactory->create(FormOneType::class,null,[]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //do some action, persist object...
        //create a flashbag
        //redirect to some page
    }
    return $this->render("template.html.twig",array(
        'formOne'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/form-2", name="route_handle_form_2")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function handleFormTwoAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->formFactory->create(FormTwoType::class,null,[]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //do some action, persist object...
        //create a flashbag
        //redirect to some page

    }
    return $this->render("template.html.twig",array(
        'formTwo'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

}
```

I use twig extension because I think you want to use the 3 forms in all templates, if you dont need that, you can avoid the twig extension and create the 3 forms only in the controller who render the page where are the forms